# Error in D3 visualization (Stacked Area Chart)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to use this template (d3 code inside):
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211#data.tsv
and just update the data with my own data. I got a problem ,as shown in this picture:
[image]

How can I set the Axis properly to the data?
the `y` axis should be from 0 until the max of total sum all of the columns.
and the `x` axis should be from 1 until 27.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.browser text {
  text-anchor: end;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();




var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
     .tickFormat(d3.format(".s"));

//
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.User_ID); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });
//
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("aggData.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "User_ID"; }));



  function User_ID(d) {
      d.User_ID = +d.User_ID;
      return d;
    }

  var browsers = stack(color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {User_ID: d.User_ID, y: d[name] / 100};
      })
    };
  }));



  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return 40 })]);
  var browser = svg.selectAll(".browser")
      .data(browsers)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "browser");

  browser.append("path")
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
/*
  browser.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.User_ID) + "," + y(d.value.y0 + d.value.y / 2) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", -6)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
*/
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
});

</script>
```

and my TSV data is:

```
  User_ID   RegisteredUsers SuperUsers  Executives
1   477 2238    981
2   189 1829    1324
3   894 27  2242
4   285 1773    1157
5       1291    64  2295
6   284 769 2653
7   1241    559 1210
8   759 920 1398
9   872 36  2320
10  352 1804    905
11  309 2358    778
12  1013    36  2183
13  928 441 22
14  2658    735 1189
15  1040    1353    1005
16  1427    746 1612
17  749 101 2246
18  925 41  2298
19  106 64  3231
20  619 203 2070
21  391 2203    728
22  755 139 2263
23  696 248 2080
24  1883    0   1785
25  1028    123 1866
26  626 286 2070
27  1128    145 1864
```

(The key of each row is `User_ID` )

Comment: I think one issue definitely comes from the fact that your user IDs are not numbers. For example, `d3.extent` of an array of strings is probably screwing up your domain when you execute `x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.User_ID; }));`.

Comment: Hi thanks, 
I tried now to change all the user_ID to numbers (The usernames not relavanet for me..) but it still doesn't show nothing.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the [web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)?

Comment: Yes:
Uncaught ReferenceError: formatPercent is not defined
ok I see this variable..just a sec

Comment: Okay, since I don't think you're visualizing time/date data, you need to update your x-axis to be a `d3.scale.linear()`, and you need to remove the line `.tickFormat(formatPercent);` from your `yAxis`.

Comment: Hi Thanks again,
I updated my post.
Its give me diffrent console error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out in your question, your main issue is in setting the domains. The `x` domain is pretty simple, you just want to find the maximum value of the `User_ID`s:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return +d.User_ID; }));
```

The `y` domain is more complicated. Unlike in the example you linked to, the domain of your values is not `[0, 1]` -- which is the default for [`d3.scale.linear()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear). You can calculate the domain directly from your input data, however, which is what you asked about in your question. The only wrinkle is that for each object (row in your table), you need to take the maximum column:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        // return the maximum value of any column
        return d3.max(color.domain().map(function(n){ return +d[n]; }));
    })
]);
```

The only other change you need to make is to stop normalizing your data by dividing by 100:

```
var browsers = stack(color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {User_ID: d.User_ID, y: +d[name]}; // previously y: d[name]/100
        })
    };
}));
```

And violá, here's what you get:

[image: stacked bar graph made after incorporating the changes from my answer]